# Apple watch always-on sweep second hand

Tags: apple-watch

I would like to use my Apple watch during patient assessment as an EMT. In order to do so I need a sweep second hand that is always displayed, otherwise I'll need to wear an analog watch for assessments.

I've tried using the Infograph watch face but when the watch face dims to its always-on status the second hand disappears. I need to reactivate the watch with a wrist-flick in order to get it displaying again.

Are there any watch faces that will continue to display a sweep second hand while the watch is in its dimmed, always-on mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No watch face is allowed to update often when dimmed to save battery.

You can make the watch face stay on for longer before dimming when turned on by tapping. Go to Watch settings on Apple Watch or the Watch app on iOS, choose General → Wake Screen and set On Tap: Wake for 70 Seconds.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of the wake on tap setting. Unfortunately, I need something that will last significantly longer.